# How to get underlined headings

Tags: sectioning, formatting, cv, underline

I would like to get underlined section headings that look like the lines under "Professional Experience" and "Education" in this [example](https://resumegenius.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Electrical-Engineer-Resume-Sample-2015.jpg). I would preferably like to do this without switching to a resume-documentclass.

Also, if there is a way to have an linewidth underline under centered text and then have some smaller text centered below that underline, that would be great. (So, like underlining a name and then having contact information under the underline.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Can you please provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/54029) to show what you have tried already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have adapted a reply given [Underlining a whole line with a short text in its beginning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18768/underlining-a-whole-line-with-a-short-text-in-its-beginning) But there is a small limitation the Section title should be smaller than linewidth.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}  %% Needed for calculating remaining length. 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\remaining}
\newcommand{\titleline}[1]{%
\setlength{\remaining}{\textwidth-\widthof{\textsc{#1}}}
\noindent\underline{\textsc{#1}\hspace*{\remaining}}\par}
\begin{document}

\titleline{Section Underlined}

\lipsum

\titleline{In case if I use a bigger line as a section title this command may behave weirdly }


\end{document}
```

MWE would have helped better.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are asking two questions at the same time here. However, regarding the main part you could do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\myresumesection[1]{%
  \section*{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
  \raisebox{2em}[0pt][0pt]{\rule{\textwidth}{.5pt}}
}

\begin{document}
\myresumesection{Professional experience}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: solution_rendered]