# Underlining a whole line with texts at different spots

Tags: spacing, underline

I would like to underline the whole line with texts anywhere I choose on the line. [I found this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18769/180788), which is almost what I want. I tried

```
\titleline{homework \hfill assignment}
```

but it does not output what I expect. Why is that?
Also, here is a visualization of what I want to produce:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a large number of ways one can achieve this. Here's one using a `tabular` for the "underline":

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\titleline}[3]{%
  \par\noindent
  \begin{tabular}{ @{} p{\linewidth} @{} }
    \makebox[0pt][l]{#1}\hfill
    \makebox[0pt][c]{#2}\hfill
    \makebox[0pt][r]{#3} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\titleline{Left}{Center}{Right}

\titleline{Very long left}{Medium center}{R}

\end{document}
```